# Legendary badge awarded early

Tags: support, reputation, badges

When I check my reputation with https://stackoverflow.com/reputation, it shows that

> ```
> days represented 305
> rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 126 days
> earned at least 200 reputation on 149 days
> earned 58 reputation from suggested edits
> ```

Though it says that I got 200 rep on 149 days only, I already got the [Legendary badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/146/legendary?userid=1903116). Why did I get the badge one day earlier?

Comment: The stats on that page are not 100% accurate.

Comment: @animuson Will that be fixed?

Comment: Well, keep in mind that the page doesn't show deleted posts. So any deleted posts you have that are still gaining you reputation would never show up there and would always throw off those stats. As for other small nuances: highly doubtful. That page is mostly obsolete. They were originally going to just remove it entirely. I'm not really sure why they didn't.

Comment: @animuson But the cumulative reputation shown in that page is accurate.

Comment: That doesn't mean the stats are. Different functions.

Comment: See [Epic badge received too early?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85363) Every day you cross 200 points is counted, but if a post is deleted *later* those days still count but are no longer reflected as such in `/reputation`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks :-) That extensively answers this question.

Comment: @thefourtheye: it says the same thing as Animuson, really. The `/reputation` log is an audit log of your *current* reputation total. The counts towards epic and legendary on that page should be seen as estimates, at best.

Comment: Don't forget that the criteria for the Epic and Legendary badges were changed to be only based on [hitting 200 without downvotes factored in](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173381/why-dont-i-have-the-mortarboard-badge/181103#181103).  None of the metrics on the `/reputation` page show the result of this new calculation, so it is not easy to see how close you really are.