# Is /reputation a secret feature of Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-audit

> https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

This shows a cryptic map of my entire reputation history. What is this, and is it documented anywhere?

Comment: It's not really a secret. But it hasn't been in use for a while (even though it still works).

Comment: Since the rep updates itself automatically this page is not that important anymore. it was in ancient times.

Comment: It's documented here [How do I audit my reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43005/245167)

Comment: Indeed. That is very cryptic. No CSS, no graph, no map. just pretty boring text.

Comment: @user0000000 You forgot *parsable*.

Comment: Well, it's not a secret any more.

Comment: Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/46696

Comment: @user0000000 as someone who used to play text adventures, I'm _imagining_ a glossy, translucent line chart with rainbows. There are exits to the South and East.

Comment: @Gareth: be careful, you may be eaten by a grue. :-)

Comment: what is "earned 0 reputation from suggested edits"

Comment: @Daniel A. White : Users with < 2000 rep can edit things, and people with > 2000 rep can approve the suggested edit, and the lower rep user will receive 2 points per edit.

Comment: @rpm dang. i never had that.

Comment: It's a treasure map, don't tell anyone but!

Comment: I am shocked. Really that many people didn't know about /reputation ???

Comment: Thanks god it's not a secret, because you are not very discreet...

Comment: But did you know about `/reputation?give=1000`?

Comment: thanks, with `/reputation` it's easier to find the downvotes I got (I search for (-2) inside the content), inside the profile it's nearly impossible to find this information

Answer (score 65, accepted):

It's been around for quite a while, and was more widely used before reputation became a mostly 'real time' indicator. It not only gave you a breakdown (in audit form) of all your wonderful points, it also pointed out when there was a discrepancy between your displayed reputation, and your *actual* reputation (or most often, what your rep would be reduced to if there were a re-calc). You used to be able to trigger a re-calc from that page, but we found that the ability hid bugs, so that feature was removed.

Now that we do basically instant recalculation it's sort of antiquated, you can get a much better audit of your points from viewing the reputation area of your profile. I doubt that we'd ever get rid of the `/reputation` page (can't make promises) but for *most* things, we'd point people to their profile instead.

Comment: Profile page doesn't show e.g. how much was earned through suggested edits

Comment: I still use it for a better breakdown of the rep caps, and it's a valuable ([but inaccurate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256170/legendary-badge-awarded-early)) tool to measure progress to the legendary badge.

Comment: `/reputation` shows *earned at least 200 reputation on 148 days*, but I was awarded with *Legendary* badge several days ago. Which one is broken? `/reputation` or badge system?

Comment: should be in the dashboard,in fact the data in that page is quite usefull.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: Neither. Have a look at the link in my comment titled "but inaccurate", and the [epic badge received too early](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85363/epic-badge-received-too-early) post

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek That page is confusing. There's three ways one could hit 200 rep represented there, Reached, Exceeded, and Exceeded but didn't reach. I know the third sounds goofy, but you can get 200 rep in a day without actually gaining it through votes (bounties, suggested edits, etc). If you sum up the number of times you reached (148) with the number of times you _exceeded_ (e.g. acceptance bonus is immune to the rep-cap) (90), you're more than eligible for the badge.