# Reputation change dataset

Tags: feature-request, reputation, reputation-history, personal-data

Is there a way to obtain all daily changes in reputation of a user (or your own account) in the form of a time series?
The result could be something like:

```
Date        Reputation
01-01-2019  1
02-01-2019  21
10-05-2019  20
11-05-2019  45
```

etc.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234414/158100

Comment: Hmmm, not exactly what I asked for but it is a good start.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280569/add-reputation-history-to-sede

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/reputation maybe?

Comment: @ivarni How did you find that url?

Comment: @JonasWilms Somewhere on meta. Can't recall where I saw it first. Googling for the actual URL returns (among many other things) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261400/957731. It's not very known but it gets brought up once in a while, usually when someone has questions about rep calculation.